# Disable and activate FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to initially set the editable, selectable, droppable and events to false (or not), when the user clicks a button, retrieves the data successfully, then set them to true. I'm a newbie and I don't know how to handle it with js

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        height: function () {
            return $(window).height() * 0.7;
        },
        allDaySlot: false,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

        //Here is the part I want to add after receiving user submitted data
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        droppable: true,
        events: "...",
```

Comment: By default make there values false and when the submit button clicked you can use the same instance variable `calender.editable` to true.

Comment: Can you write me an example? I have yet to succeed with it

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dynamic-options shows you how to set options to new values after you have initialised the calendar.

Comment: Thanks, let me try

Comment: Great, it succeeded. I spent a lot of time trying to rewrite it in js without knowing FullCalendar has support. Really thank you very much @ADyson

Comment: No problem. Always read the documentation thoroughly, you can save yourself a lot of time :-)